# How to run multiple functions and create a list?

Tags: python, ccxt

I'm new to Python and I have a list of crypto exchanges I would like to connect with the `ccxt` library in order to fetch OHLC data.

But instead to instantiate each exchanges classes one by one (many objects), I would like to create an `exchanges` object containing all the exchanges data in a list, so that I could request data of the first exchange with `exchanges[0]`, data from the second with `exchanges[1]`, etc.

```
import ccxt # import module

ex_bitfinex = ccxt.bitfinex()
ex_binance = ccxt.binance()
ex_okcoinusd = ccxt.okcoinusd()
...

ex = ["bitfinex",
      "binance",
      "okcoinusd"]

# This doesn't return the expected result
exchanges = ccxt.ex()
```

With [r](/questions/tagged/r) I would use `lapply()` but how could I achieve this in Python?

Comment: What is the expected result, could we have the current output along with an example of what should be the desired output ?

Comment: It's not clear why you think defining a local list of strings would add a function to the `ccxt` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `getattr(...)` and a list comp.

```
exchanges = [getattr(ccxt, e)() for e in ex]
```

Then you can access all three exchanges by index.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I can access the `id` property with `exchanges[0].id` but as soon as I request over multiple index it fails `exchanges[0:2].id`

Comment: @Florent you have to use another list comp. `[e.id for e in exchanges]` whenever you want to apply something to multiple items in a list. If you want to .id a list, the list has to be a custom subclass of list with its custom `__getattr__` method.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
exchanges = [ccxt.bitfinex(), ccxt.binance(), ccxt.okcoinusd()]
```